# Optimizing ARM absolute jump

Tags: performance, optimization, assembly, arm

I would like to do the following operation in ARM assembly with only 24 bytes of code/data. Is it possible?

PC = [MEMLOC] + PC

Or, put into words, I would like to jump ahead based on a PC-relative offset which is read from memory.

The value read from MEMLOC must be a full 32-bit word

I can do this easily with 16 [<-updated from 32 before] bytes (using  standard LDR and ADD instructions), but looking to optimize away one instruction. Anyone know if this is possible? I think there are ways to do with a ~20 bit word read from memory, but it may not be possible with a full 32-bit word.

Update: Here is what I have:

```
LDR R12, =MEMLOC1
ADD R12, PC, R12
LDR PC, [R12]

MEMLOC1: (contains 32-bit word)
```

Comment: Do you expect a large savings by removing one instruction?  Accessing memory to get this offset is likely to blow away any gain, I'd think.

Comment: show us what you have now that you are trying to improve upon?

Comment: I added an update to my original post containing the way to do this with 4 bytes of instruction and data. I actually don't need the 32-bit word to be read from memory, but from what I have seen there is no way to store a 32-bit value inside an instruction so this seems necessary.

Comment: Eliminating an instruction won't matter much. You've got at least a 1 clock stall waiting for the read of your 32-bit value to complete.

Comment: I think you cant get shorter than four words (three instructions plus the offset), a word is 4 bytes and you have four words which is 16 bytes so you have 8 bytes to spare as it stands now.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo where I said 32 bytes instead of 16 bytes. I can do it in 16 bytes and looking to do it in 12 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution actually takes 36 bytes because the first ldr probably causes a memory pool entry containing the address of MEMLOC1 to be generated in your text (unless your linker is smart enough to fix that).

In 24 bytes you can do this by moving your data closer so that you can generate a pc-relative address.

```
  .text
_go:
  ldr r0, L_offset
  add pc, pc, r0
L_offset:
  .word 0x12345678
```

The offset might need to be minus a few bytes to compensate for the incremented pc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However your solution doesn't work because I want to increase PC by what is sitting at the memory location 0x12345678. Something (conceptually) like: add pc, [pc + r0] which isn't a real instruction. I apologize as I realize my initial post describing what I wanted to do was a little confusing.